# MIPS Pipeline Forwarding (double data hazard)

Tags: mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture

In the Patterson & Hennessy Book:

[image]

But can't this be handled as a EX hazard:

[image]

[image]

Why is forwarding done in the MEM stage? And how? With 1 stall (for the 2nd add, I will need result from EX in next EX)?

Comment: PS, my final link, http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2011sp/faq/faq_pa1.html says something about typos in the book: "*Note that the forward condition for MEM hazard in textbook on page 369 is WRONG!*" and I think it can be about your image.

Comment: This is clearly an error in the book (the parenthesis are unbalanced, for one). Curiously the book's most recent edition (4th Edition Revised) adds a missing closing '

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Document used http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2011sp/faq/faq_pa1.html

I'll rewrite EX and MEM hazard condition (dropping !=0 part for simplicity), before we will take in account "double data hazard" (**original rules**):

EX Hazard

```
 if (EX/MEM.RegWrite and (EX/MEM.RegisterRd == ID/EX.RegisterRs)  # =EX_h_Rs 
   ) ForwardA = 10
 if (EX/MEM.RegWrite and (EX/MEM.RegisterRd == ID/EX.RegisterRt)  # =EX_h_Rt
   ) ForwardB = 10
```

I'll call conditions  EX_h_Rs and EX_h_Rt to keep formulas shorter

MEM Hazard (original condition)

```
 if (MEM/WB.RegWrite and (MEM/WB.RegisterRd == ID/EX.RegisterRs)) ForwardA = 01 
 if (MEM/WB.RegWrite and (MEM/WB.RegisterRd == ID/EX.RegisterRt)) ForwardB = 01
```

====

And our example with two types of hazard at once, between (1st and 3rd) & (2nd and 3rd) at same time:

```
add $1, $1, $2 
add $1, $1, $3 
add $1, $1, $4
```

or (promlem cycle is marked with `**` on top and bottom)

```
                **   
add C+A -> A ... A
           v     ?  
     add B+A -> A
                v   
          add C+ A -> A     
                **
```

According to my link, after taking into account double EX + MEM hazard: (without !=0 and reordered boolean terms), **Updated rules of MEM Hazard**:

> Let's revise the forwarding conditions for MEM hazard to take care of 'double' data hazards

```
 if (MEM/WB.RegWrite and (MEM/WB.RegisterRd = ID/EX.RegisterRs) and 
  not (EX/MEM.RegWrite and (EX/MEM.RegisterRd == ID/EX.RegisterRs)) 
  ) 
   ForwardA = 01
 if (MEM/WB.RegWrite and (MEM/WB.RegisterRd = ID/EX.RegisterRt) and 
  not (EX/MEM.RegWrite and (EX/MEM.RegisterRd == ID/EX.RegisterRt)) 
 ) 
   ForwardB = 01
```

Or the same using short record of EX_h_*

```
 if (MEM/WB.RegWrite and (MEM/WB.RegisterRd = ID/EX.RegisterRs) and 
  not ( EX_h_Rs ) 
  ) 
   ForwardA = 01
 if (MEM/WB.RegWrite and (MEM/WB.RegisterRd = ID/EX.RegisterRt) and 
  not ( EX_h_Rt ) 
 ) 
   ForwardB = 01
```

which means:

Try to forward from MEM/WB to EX; if there is no forward into same input operand from EX/MEM pipeline registers.

Or the same

Don't even try to forward from MEM/WB to EX; if there is already forwarding of more recent result from EX/MEM.

I'll try to illustrate:

```
add C+A -> A     A'
                 v?  (forwarding to 3rd instruction) 
           A -> A''
                v?
          add C+A -> A
```

so, for third instruction original rules will say that Both `A'` from first instruction and `A''` from second instruction should be forwarded (but mux can't be fed from two sources at single moment of time). And modifying of MEM hazard condition says that `A'` should not be tryed to forward if there is active forwarding of `A''` which is more recent.

So; *your drawing is right,* **there will be 2 EX Hazards forwarding**; But MEM hazard forwarding should not be tried if there is already active EX Hazard forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly an error in the book's 4th edition (the parenthesis are unbalanced, for one). Curiously the book's most recent edition (4th Edition Revised) adds a missing closing ')' but... ends up with an incorrect condition **still**:

[image]

I think this would be the correct version of the conditions:

```
if (MEM/WB.RegWrite
and (MEM/WB.RegisterRd ≠ 0)
and not(EX/MEM.RegWrite and (EX/MEM.RegisterRd ≠ 0)
       and (EX/MEM.RegisterRd = ID/EX.RegisterRs))
and (MEM/WB.RegisterRd = ID/EX.RegisterRs)) Forward = 01

if (MEM/WB.RegWrite
and (MEM/WB.RegisterRd ≠ 0)
and not(EX/MEM.RegWrite and (EX/MEM.RegisterRd ≠ 0)
       and (EX/MEM.RegisterRd = ID/EX.RegisterRt))
and (MEM/WB.RegisterRd = ID/EX.RegisterRt)) Forward = 01
```